# Would deleting a Linked List recursively cause a stack overflow?

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion, memory-management, linked-list

I have a linked list build out of `Node` objects:

```
class Node {
   public:
      Node(string data);
      Node* GetNext() const;
      void SetNext(Node* nextNode);
      ~Node();
   private:
      string data;
      Node* next;
};
```

The destructor is defined below:

```
Node::~Node() {
   delete next;
}
```

Where the destructor should be called on the head `Node`.

My question is this: would deleting the singly-linked list like this cause a Stack Overflow on large lists (it works fine on small i.e., < 10 size lists). If it does, would it be better to use an iterative solution, like

```
while (head->GetNext() != 0) {
   Node* temp = head->GetNext();
   head->SetNext(temp->GetNext());
   delete temp;
}
delete head;
```

where there is no defined constructor for `Node`?

Comment: I don't get these strange implementations of a linked list, where the Node is destroying itself and any other node in the chain.  What if I want to delete a single node out of the list, what would I do?  The better option is to create a linked list class, where a member is a node pointer, and the linked list class deletes and allocates nodes as it sees fit.  The Node class should not have any user-defined destructor at all.

Comment: It can *easily* cause a stack overflow. Throw a million nodes on your linked list and give it a try.

Comment: "would deleting the singly-linked list like this cause a Stack Overflow on large lists". Definitely,and it should be very easy for you to test this yourself

Comment: The iterative version is better for Stack Overflow, since it is not recursive. Why not implementing the destruction in a `class List` that has a `Node* head`?

Comment: Well, we're talking about dynamically allocated pointers here, so technically, I think we're talking about a heap overflow.

Comment: Ah, nevermind. I misunderstood the question. I see it's not the allocation/deallocation that's being questioned, but the number of stack frame references.

Comment: Often times the compiler will convert a recursive function call into an iterative solution.  Any time tail recursion is used--no further work after recursing--the compiler can and very often will recognize this as an opportunity to reuse the caller's stack frame.  In fact some compilers are smart enough to turn non-tail recursion into tail recursion and then create the iterative version where a stack overflow will not occur.  You should test your compiler and any compiler you intend to target.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your solution is that the stack frames are continuously building up on the stacks, for each call to the `~Node()` method. Take an example of 3 `Node` objects, starting at, say `0x01`. Deletion of these has the following stack frame backtrace (I assume each Node object contains 1 bit of information, which isn't true, but it makes the list a bit neater):

```
 (0) Node (0x01): ~Node
 (1) Node (0x02): ~Node
 (2) Node (0x03): ~Node
```

So, for a million `Node` objects, you will have a million stack frames *before the first one even completes*. Each stack frame takes up space on the stack, so, yes, you could run out of stack space.

The iterative solution doesn't suffer from this problem, because, for each iteration, the call to delete a `Node` completes *before* the next `Node` deletion routine runs. This means that you have a single function call on the stack during each iteration (plus or minus the amount you need to complete that function call, but in particular, it's not *recursive*).

In addition to that problem, there's another problem that's been raised, and that is that you don't have any way of deleting just a single `Node` object. You can either delete the whole list or part of the list. Imagine what would happen if a client had a reference to `Node (0x02)` in the previous example, and called `delete node`. In this case, `Node (0x02)` and `Node (0x03)` would be deleted, but `Node (0x01)` would _still have a reference to the pointer to the memory for `Node (0x02)`. Dereferencing this would cause a crash.

Answer (score 4):

The stack size always limits the depth of recursive calls on a function. Even with the destructor (and other functions without a parameter) it's necessary to keep the return address of that function call (the destructor would get the `this` pointer as implicit parameter anyways).

So from a certain upper limit of `Node`s the stack will overflow, yes.

The iterative way is much more robust regarding this.